Why is the additive loop height independent of the universal Chern class?
I am currently working my way through section 3.1 of Andrew Stacey and Sarah Whitehouse's "Stable and unstable operations in mod (p) cohomology theories", Algebr. Geom. Topol. 8, No. 2, 1059-1091 (2008), arxiv:math.0605471, MR2443108, Zbl 1153.55016.
In 3.2 and 3.3, the $E$-additive loop height of $F^*(-)$ is being defined. But I am unable to verify that it does not depend on the choice of the universal Chern class $x^F$. Neither I am able to understand why, if both theories are $p$-local, there is an upper bound for $h$ given by $2(p^n-1)/(p-1)$.
I tried to compute identities for all of the variables involved and I suppose that the $b_i$ (and hence the $c_i$) do not depend on the choice of $x^F$. The argument given in the paper is that only terms of lower order appear when altering the $g_i$. If $j>k/2$, $c_j$, being the coefficient of $s^k$ in $b(s)^{k}$, is divisible by $b_1$ at least $k-2i$ times, and maybe this fact has something to do with those "lower order terms". But I have not been able to come up with a proof yet.
